# Rails 3.1 table_builder's calendar_for table rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the [table_builder](https://github.com/p8/table_builder) gem to display bookings within a calendar view however I seem to be missing something as the output is neither creating a table nor processing the data from the model.

booking/index.html.haml

```
%h2 Bookings

- calendar_for @bookings do |calendar|
  = calendar.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thur', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')
  - calendar.day(:day_method => :wo_date) do |date, bookings|
    = date.day
    - bookings.each do |booking|
      = booking.client.username
```

bookings_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @title = "Bookings"
    @bookings = current_user.bookings.all 
  end
```

html output

```
      <h2>Bookings</h2>
      <table><thead><tr>[[&quot;&lt;th&gt;mon&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;tue&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;wed&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;thur&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;fri&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;sat&lt;/th&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;th&gt;sun&lt;/th&gt;&quot;]]</tr></thead>
      <tbody><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
```

The end view
[image: The view]

Comment: Try to use `!=` as your devault settings for HAML seems to escape html outputs of `table_for`.